# Fastlane unable to load FTP plugin

Tags: ftp, fastlane

I am unable to use fastlane since it gives me error on every command (including: fastlane install plugins, fastlane update plugins....)

```
Error loading plugin 'fastlane-plugin-ftp': cannot load such file -- net/ftp
+------------------------+---------+------------------------+
|                       Used plugins                        |
+------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| Plugin                 | Version | Action                 |
+------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| fastlane-plugin-ftp    | 0.1.5   | No actions found       |
| fastlane-plugin-fireb  | 0.3.4   | firebase_app_distribu  |
| ase_app_distribution   |         | tion,                  |
|                        |         | firebase_app_distribu  |
|                        |         | tion_add_testers,      |
|                        |         | firebase_app_distribu  |
|                        |         | tion_get_latest_relea  |
|                        |         | se,                    |
|                        |         | firebase_app_distribu  |
|                        |         | tion_get_udids,        |
|                        |         | firebase_app_distribu  |
|                        |         | tion_login,            |
|                        |         | firebase_app_distribu  |
|                        |         | tion_remove_testers    |
+------------------------+---------+------------------------+

[!] No actions were found while loading one or more plugins
    Please use `bundle exec fastlane` with plugins
    More info - https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/using-plugins/#run-with-plugins
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion to run `bundle exec fastlane` instead of just `fastlane`? This is required if you installed the plugin via `Gemfile`. If that doesn't work please try the other suggestions on the [fastlane troubleshooting page](https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/plugins-troubleshooting/) and add more detail about your problem (what you tried and what worked/didn't). Right now your question doesn't have enough detail to confidently give a good answer.

Comment: Yes I tried both bundle exec fastlane and all the advices from fastlane troubleshooting page. But nothing helped, it always gives me this same error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my RN application. Seems like there no [net-ftp](https://github.com/ruby/net-ftp) module. Then I added

```
...
gem 'net-ftp'
gem 'fastlane-plugin-ftp'
```

to my Pluginfile. After this run `fastlane install_plugins` in your fastlane directory. This change solve the problem.

You can also install it by
`$ gem install net-ftp`